# Poisson process: waiting time probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

How can i calculate the probabilities for the situations 1), 2) and 3) ?

Q: A radioactive source emits particles according to a poisson process of rate $\lambda=2$ particles per minute.

1) What is the probability that the first particle appears after 3min?

on this first one would that be the probability that nothing happens from 0 to 3, and then anything can happen from there and out? How should I set-up and calculate this?

2) What is the probability that the first particle appears some time after 3min and before 5min?

3) What is the probability that exactly one particle is emitted in the interval from 3 to 5 min.

Here is some of the notation/theory that I am familiar with

$W_n$ is the time of occurence of the nth event. $W_n$ ~$gamma(n,lambda)$. $W_1$ exponentially distributed.

$S_n=W_{n+1} -W_n$ measures the duration the poisson process sojourns in state $n$. $S_0$,$S_1$,..., are independent random variables having the exponential distribution $\lambda e^{-\lambda *s}$

$N((s,t])$ is a rv that counts the number of events occuring in an interval $(s,t]$

$P(N((s,t])=k)=\frac{[\lambda(t-s)]^k e^{-\lambda(t-s)}}{k!}$

Obviously I am also familiar with all the stuff about independent increments and the basic definition $P(X(s+t)-X(s)=k)$ is poisson($\lambda t$) and $X(0)=0$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint for 1**

Given your last sentence, the number of things happen from time zero to three is Poisson distributed with mean six. So what's the probability that zero things happen? (i.e. What's the probability that a Poisson variable with mean six takes the value zero?)

Comment: actually I figured out 2),$W_1$ is the occurence of the first. All I had to do was calculate the probability that this occur between 3 and 5, and I already know the distribution of $W_1$ (exponential)  So I just integrate the pdf of $W_1$ from 3 to 5.

So now only 3) remains, do you know that one? is it just $P(N(3,5]=1)$?

Comment: Yes. The number of particles admitted in the interval is poisson with mean four so you just need the probability that this is one.